# MySQL PDO multiple UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to update a tinyint to 1 where ID is a given variable, and reset all the others to 0.

This of course doesn't work but gives the sense of what I'm trying to do

```
$var = @$_POST['id'] ;
$stmt = $db-> prepare("UPDATE message SET live = 1 WHERE id = :var; UPDATE message SET live = 0 WHERE NOT id = :var");
$stmt->execute(['var' => $var]);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but can you not just prepare and execute two separate statements?

Comment: Yes but I was looking for a compact solution and @Akina solution works perfectly

Comment: Not every "compact" solution is a good solution. Fast forward a couple months, you: wtf this code is meant to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to update a tinyint to 1 where ID is a given variable, and reset all the others to 0.

```
UPDATE message 
SET live = (id = :var);
```